# Angular 6 subscribe

Tags: angular-6

Console.log retorno undefined

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

Service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getCentrosCustos() {
  return this.http.get<CentroCusto[]>(API);
}
```

Component:

```
centrosCustos: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.centroCustoService.getCentrosCustos().subscribe(dados => {
        this.centrosCustos = dados;
        console.log(this.centrosCustos);
    });
}
```

Comment: Seu console log precisa ser colocado dentro da instrução subscribe, pois é uma função assincrona, no momento do console log, sua variavel não foi preenchida ainda

Comment: @EduardoGonçalves, eu fiz conforme sua orientação e continua exibindo undefined.

Comment: Porque o `console.log` é executado antes do callback do `subscribe`

Comment: @EduardoGonçalves, editei o código.

Comment: Se voce der o console log em dados, o resultado esta correto ? Pois seu codigo esta correto agora, pode realmente estar undefined seu retorno da funcao getCentrosCustos()

Comment: @EduardoGonçalves, agora deu certo, entendi como funciona. Obrigado!